# Show an element on click

Tags: html

I have been playing around for ages with this and it does not seem to work.

I am looking to add a hidden voucher code function to my site and have it so that the code is actually hidden until the "click to reveal" button is clicked and user's browser opens a new window.

I have a [test page](http://www.xclo.co.uk/testing.html) with exactly what i'm talking about.

my trouble is, everything works but the actual voucher reveal bit.

Any ideas, or any link on how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to use javascript?

Comment: why with the "DOT"s there's no need for that here, we want to help, but don't make us work towards that help. Aside from that though, what is the real issue, can you provide some code the html, the javascript, css, other that you are currently attempting to use? You could provide a jsfiddle.net example which will allow us to see easier whats going on.

Comment: This may be off-topic, but I just want to note that your comments in HTML should be between `<!-- -->`tags, not `/* */`. Everyone can see your comments in your test page.

Comment: which is what my intention was so you could see which one is which.

Answer (score 1):

Your page looks like you're trying to use jQuery code, but you have not added jQuery to your document, and thus are receiving errors like `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

See [jQuery: The Basics](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#jQuery%3a_The_Basics) on how you can set up your page to point to jQuery properly.

Comment: That's not exactly how StackOverflow works; the scores attributed to your question are not related to any of the answers.  Also, any users may opt to upvote or downvote questions/answers at their will.  You can't have say over whether others upvote or downvote you.  You may wish to check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for information on how to ask good questions (which hopefully won't be downvoted).  Best of luck!

Comment: how can I ask an more questions when people downvote me for no reason meaning I can not ask any more. all I want is to ask more questions relating to programming. As I have more experience now, I believe that I can now ask a justified question (like the one about my database not working in php no matter what code I use to try) but can not because of people down voting me which has blocked this feature. when I edit my past questions. no one notices and there for no one up votes me. Can I please ask how this is fair?

Comment: Well I certainly am not in a position of enforcing fairness, but perhaps a few tips: (a) See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on making your question complete and concise, (b) Try to get your question right the first time (as you've mentioned, people don't always see edits), (c) It's not always going to be fair.  It's an unfortunate side effect of dealing with people.  Sometimes the best you can do is just move on.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan Newmuis pointed out, your missing the jQuery lib from your code. Which that is issue one, issue two is I don't see the fancybox plugin being called in either.

so where you have this bit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".popUpCode75554").fancybox({
                'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
                'enableEscapeButton': false,
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                'hideOnContentClick': false,
                'showCloseButton': true,
                'frameWidth': 520,
                'frameHeight': 400,
                'overlayColor': '#000000',
                'callbackOnClose': function () {
                    $('.voucher-code-revealed-75554').show();
                    $('.voucher-buttons-75554').hide();
                }


            });

            $(".cashbackWarning").fancybox({
                'overlayOpacity': 0.7,
                'enableEscapeButton': false,
                'hideOnOverlayClick': true,
                'hideOnContentClick': false,
                'showCloseButton': true,
                'frameWidth': 500,
                'frameHeight': 250,
                'overlayColor': '#000000'

            });

    });

try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-11279427-1");
pageTracker._setDomainName("none");
pageTracker._setAllowLinker(true);
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
                </script>
```

add the following above it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/jquery/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

not sure how old/new that particular fancy box version is compared to the one you are attempting to use but I think it may be the newer of them. Anyway. adding those 2 lines may solve your problems unless the code you have otherwise currently is flawed somehow which doesn't appear to be the case at the moment.

On another note, if you use firefox might I suggest getting yourself an addon called firebug, it will aid you in debugging javascript based errors as well as other things.

Comment: ok thanks for all your comments guys. I have played around with it and still not working. I have still got the same problem but now I have found one [link](http://www.xclo.co.uk/free) here but this one does not link out on clicked. how can I fit the 2 together?

Comment: It depends on how the link works, if its a static html link then it should work properly. However if that same link requires some action based on javascript then you need to catch the element so to speak. The nature of fancybox is to add elements to itself dynamically. Basically creating new elements that were not originally part of the DOM when it rendered. So whats happening if this is the case your javascript is ignoring it, as technically it doesn't know its there.. However. Though many will argue it (myself included.. is you could alway use jquery `$.live()` of coure there is alternatives

Comment: Hey Kev, Im sorry to say but considering the age of the post, the lack of quality there is to it from subject to body, and the fact that the link in the post doesn't even work anymore. This Q&A does not provide any use to those who may stumble upon it in the future. There is no code displayed in your post, the example is long deleted, and all else. In all essence this original post is completely against stacks rules of posting. With that the -1 is justifiable. As this is a help forum for those to search and seek answers from.

Comment: I agree with the -1.  This is not a good question, and it's worse for *asking to be upvoted*.

Comment: how can I ask an more questions when people downvote me for no reason meaning I can not ask any more. all I want is to ask more questions relating to programming. As I have more experience now, I believe that I can now ask a justified question (like the one about my database not working in php no matter what code I use to try) but can not because of people down voting me which has blocked this feature. when I edit my past questions. no one notices and there for no one up votes me. Can I please ask how this is fair?

Comment: The down votes aren't for "no reason" they are driven by members of stack exchange that wish to see quality in the Q&A that is posted here on the service, with that, stack has a generalized rule of thumb when it comes to posting. Which you can find http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask but overall, but if you want to raise your rep again, this may help http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30910/how-do-you-increase-your-stack-overflow-reputation-in-a-realistic-manner in giving you some ideas on how to get back up there. Overall there is nothing personal here, its just a matter of how the

Comment: service generally works, and how the members generally go about using the service to keep a certain level of quality on the service.